# Compile string with custom elements

Tags: aurelia

I have an Aurelia application in which I'm trying to build a CMS component. This component will load data from the server and this data mainly contains `slug, title and content` fields.

I also have several global components defined in my application, and I want to be able to use those components in the server so when I pull that data my CMS component is able to transform/compile those custom elements.

An example would be a tab component. I have the tab component with this structure defined:

```html
<tab-panel>
    <tab title="First"></tab>
    <tab title="Second"></tab>
</tab-panel>
```

The CMS component will contain a `content` property which I use to pass a string like this: `'<tab-panel><tab title="First"></tab><tab title="Second"></tab></tab-panel>'`

The component needs to compile that string and render it in its view. I've checked the `enhance` API, but it doesn't worked, at least for me. Any other suggestion to dynamically compile/render custom elements??

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: I don't understand. Why wouldn't you have these in an aurelia template and populate / display them based on the CMS data? I mean, why wouldn't you let Aurelia handle compiling and rendering.

Comment: Because I want my content manager editor to be able to use custom component and custom attributes directly when he is writing the content for the cms page. I just build a customAttribute `cms-href` that allows to generate links between CMS pages in the frontend. That kind of stuff is what I want to have in the CMS side and be compiled by Aurelia.

Comment: Using InlineViewStratege and `compose` element I was able to do this. But the `cms-href` has bindings and the binding is not working. It seems than InlineViewStrategy doesn't have bindings into account for some reason...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the solution. I've used a `compose` element and InlineViewStrategy and it worked well, the components are shows and binding works as expected.

Answer (score 0):

If your custom elements are registered globally using `globalResources` you can actually using the `TemplatingEngine` to dynamically insert content into the DOM and then compile it after-the-fact. [This blog post](http://ilikekillnerds.com/2016/01/enhancing-at-will-using-aurelias-templating-engine-enhance-api/) goes into detail in how you can do it.

However, I would use this as a last resort. As is mostly always the case, there are much better ways to do something in Aurelia. Using the `<compose>` element is a great way to dynamically render content in your Aurelia applications and should always be the first port of call.